# How to zoom to left edge of the current range in Highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Take the official demo for range selector as an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/rangeselector/allbuttonsenabled-true/

When selecting a different range button, like from `6m` to `3m`, or from `6m` to `1y`, the range will shrink or grow while the right edge of the range will remain still.

Is there any way to keep the left edge of the range, and move the right edge to update the range?

Comment: Hi, you could overwrite default clickButton function with modified one, example of wrapping a function: http://jsfiddle.net/uao4nejf/

Comment: @stpoa I will have a careful look on that example. Thank you!